# how to read from cdc tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, change-data-capture

I wanted to try out the `change data capture` feature of sql server, but I cannot get it to work

What I did

```
-- enable cdc
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db

-- enable it on a table, for testing
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table  
@source_schema = N'dbo',  
@source_name   = N'tblUser',  
@role_name     = NULL,  
@supports_net_changes = 1

-- check if it got enabled (yes it did)
select t.name, t.is_tracked_by_cdc,
from sys.tables t where name = 'tblUser'
```

So, now I just changed some value in a row in that table, and next I wanted to see how it looks.
So I noticed that a schema `cdc` is created in `system tables` with some tables, so I thought let's see what is in table cdc.dbo_tblUser_CT

but then I get this

[image]

So now I am stuck.
What must I do to see the changed data ?

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64)
> Jan 12 2022 22:30:08   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 
> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Compatibility level is 150

Comment: Please upgrade your SSMS and see if it works - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57300305/9853823

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin But then I cannot debug anymore, that is why I stick with version 17 (and everyone I know also does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Learning_DBAdmin, you should always use the [latest series of SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#download-ssms). That is likely you're issue here. The 17 series of SSMS is quite old at this point.

Otherwise you can try manually writing out the script `SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM cdc.dbo_tblUser_CT` that SSMS would've generated for you. (Replace `*` with the actual column names.)

I know you mentioned you still use the 17 series of SSMS for its debugging capabilities, but the longer you hold onto that version the more issues you'll find yourself running into. Instead, [Visual Studio can debug SQL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079275/Debug-Stored-Procedures-in-Visual-Studio-and-SSMS) nowadays. Please see this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41262963/5059085) on how to set it up.

Comment: `Instead, Visual Studio can debug SQL nowadays` Yeah if you have tons of time figuring out how, and why its not working again today... The debug functionality should come back to SSMS. Also, sometimes I have procedures that I do not use in a VS project, it is so much work to set that up

Comment: And what do people have to use when the do not have VS ? Sql Server is also used in other projects...

Comment: @GuidoG Unfortunately that seems to be your only options, but the StackOverflow answer I linked was pretty simple sounding. Also unfortunately that's outside anyone's control except Microsoft's, and with Azure Data Studio being the latest iteration, I'm guessing it's doubtful that debugging is coming back to SSMS.

Comment: @GuidoG To your follow up question, Visual Studio is free and can still be used to just debug the SQL code, even without an application code project running in it.

Comment: It seems the idiots at microsoft have done it again... So now I have 2 versions of SSMS installed, one to be able to debug and one for having the latest version. I agree only microsoft could fix this. I just don't understand why it had to be removed from SSMS, am I missing something here ?

Comment: Though I do not like your answer (nothing personal I just would have liked it not being version dependend) it is correct off course